# Is there a way to turn the hover panel off for the Groups card in SharePoint sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups, modern-team-site

In the modern SharePoint interface for Group (Team) sites, if you hover over the team name in the top left corner of the site, it pops up with the contact card for the Group.

Is there a way we can turn this off? We want to create the Team sites and give read access to other departments and we dont want them to access this contact card.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, there is no OOB way to do that.

For modern pages, you can configure [modern script editor web part](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d4b8b3c4-8950-4407-9120-204b80fc35f9/sharepoint-online-best-practice-install-modern-script-editor-web-part-for-sharepoint-online?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing) and use Javascript code to hide the hover panel.

However, for modern libraries/lists' view pages, there is no way to add custom code currently. So, I am afraid that you are unable to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you for this. Are there any plans to introduce such a feature?